# Keeping state of input breaks app when value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a form to work, which acts both as a creation- and an update-form for an item. I keep track of an `edit` state to decide what text should be rendered in the form and what API call to make on submitting it. So far so good, that all works well. In order to keep track of the input values, I use a hook `useInputState` to update the corresponding state value:

**useInputState.js**

```
export default (initialVal) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialVal);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    } else {        // to be able to set state manually
      setValue(e);
    }
  };
  const reset = () => {
    setValue("");
  };
  return [value, handleChange, reset];
};
```

```
const [newTitle, setNewTitle, resetNewTitle] = useInputState();
```

**form.js**

```
export default function Form({
  newTitle,
  setNewTitle,
  edit, // true or false
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{edit ? "Edit Item" : "Add new item"}</h2>
      <div>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="What is your title?"
          value={newTitle}
          onChange={setNewTitle}
        />
      </div>
  )
}
```

Now when the user adds a new item, obviously the form is empty to begin with. However, when the user wants to edit an item, I try to prepopulate the form with the information of the given object. This is where I run into issues: The object model has some optional fields. When the user leaves these blank when creating the object, editing it breaks the application with an error of `can't read property target of null`.

I use the following code to prepoulate the form fields when edit is toggled on:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (edit && selectedItem) {
      setNewTitle(selectedItem.title);
    }
  }, [edit]);
```

I see why it's running into issues and I tried a lot of things like changing the setNewTitle argument to `setNewTitle(selectedItem["title"] !== undefined ?  selectedItem.title : "");` and similar approaches but nothing has worked so far.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: console selectedItem["title"] , what it gives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are only comparing `selectedItem.title !== undefined` which can result in a specified error if your `selectedItem.title` is equal to `null`;
There are multiple ways to solve the issue but you can do the following:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  if (!!e && e.target) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  } else {        // to be able to set state manually
    setValue(e);
  }
};
```

The change is in the line: `if (!!e && e.target)`

Answer (score 0):

In your `useInputState` hook, you assume that `handleChange` function is a `React.ChangeEvent` meaning it is passed with `e` : `Event` from which you read `e.target.value`. This breaks when you try to set the value directly here in this line, in useEffect:

```
setNewTitle(selectedItem.title);
```

I would suggest a change like this to your `useInputState` hook,

```
 export default (initialVal) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialVal);
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    if (value) {
      setValue(value);
    } else {        
      setValue("");
    }
  };
  const reset = () => {
    setValue("");
  };
  return [value, handleChange, reset];
};
```

then i your form do this,

```
 export default function Form({
      newTitle,
      setNewTitle,
      edit, // true or false
    }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{edit ? "Edit Item" : "Add new item"}</h2>
          <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="What is your title?"
              value={newTitle}
              onChange={(e)=>setNewTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
      )
    }
```

It should work as you expect it to work with this change.

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. However, as soon as I start typing something into the input, the value changes to `[object Object]`

Comment: @PhilippK https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-sun-2sgp1 check this, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `can't read property target of null`.

So the `e` arg is falsy sometimes.

Try

```
setNewTitle(selectedItem.title ? selectedItem.title : '')
```

and in the custom hook:

```
export default (initialVal) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialVal);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if(typeof e === 'string') {
     setValue(e);
    } else if(e && e.target) {
     setValue(e.target.value);
    }
  };
  const reset = () => {
    setValue("");
  };
  return [value, handleChange, reset];
};
```